# Huawei honor 3c not recognized for development on windows?

Tags: android

I am new to android development.I want to test my app on Huawei honor 3c but it is not recognized.I googled a lot but couldn't get answer.I downloaded and installed usb driver from huawei website too but failed to get my device for testing.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799157/testing-an-app-on-android-device-from-android-studio/

Comment: use google USB drivers. They should work.